# Iterate ArrayList and check against all other elements

Tags: java, arraylist, compare, distance, loops

I'm trying to check all values in an ArrayList against all other values, removing one if they are too close in value. Here's an example:

```
// make an ArrayList of random numbers
ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
  int rand = int(random(255));
  nums.add(rand);
  println(rand);  
}

// go through all numbers and compare
// (loop backwards to prevent ConcurrentModificationException)
for (int i = nums.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  int current = nums.get(i);
  println("Current #: " + current);

  // how to do this?
  // not sure if there's a faster way that
  // would avoid running through the entire 
  // ArrayList for every element...
  for (Integer other : nums) {
    if (abs(current - other) < 5) {
      nums.remove(current);
    }
  }
}
```

Looking for the cleanest and most efficient way to do this.

[ edited for clarity ]

Comment: What's not working with the current solution? The only option I see is to first sort the ArrayList.

Comment: Why are you catching `Exception`, and what makes you think it's always because the items are the same? (Hint: look at the exception - you may be surprised...)

Comment: Why are the results "unsatisfactory"? What happens that you don't like?

Comment: -1 for ostrich/pokemon exception handling (gotta hide'em all).

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was getting problems calling ConcurrentModificationException, so this was a catch-all.

Comment: @Code-Guru: The code doesn't work! I want to compare all items in an ArrayList to all the others while deleting ones that are too close together.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Down-vote? The example code is to show one (of many) attempts - I sure there are lots of problems and am here looking for help!

Comment: @JeffThompson The point is that if you hide all exceptions, you can't reasonably debug your code - and that's what you should do.

Comment: @JeffThompson: Right - I suspected you were getting that exception, which *isn't* the same as "same item, ignore". When you get an exception, you should work out why and *fix it*. Just ignoring the exception is almost *never* the right approach - and catching `Exception` is almost never appropriate either.

Comment: Jan and Jon - fair enough.  I had so many versions and ideas for this snippet, perhaps this one wasn't the best to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better do it in a different way, in order to avoid concurrent modification and/or out of bound exceptions.

Deleting anything from a collection while iterating it, is a risky idea (imho), replacing it with adding something to another collection is much safer.

So, replace the code with equivalent, but adding objects to a new collection.

Collections are lightweight object, so creating them doesn't take much resource.

At the end assign original collection variable to the new collection.

Something like this:

```
        final ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        final ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            final int rand = Double.valueOf(Math.random() * 255).intValue();
            nums.add(rand);
        }
        System.out.println(nums);
        outer: for (Integer current : nums) {
            // result collection is reevaluated here 
            // and is not modified inside the inner for loop
            // so, accessing it is safe
            for (Integer other : result) {
                if (Math.abs(current - other) < 5) {
                    // there is a too close value, do not put, skip the check
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            // a too close value doesn't exist - add object
            result.add(current);
        }
        // here you may assing new collection to the old reference, uncomment next line
        // nums = results;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex - for me at least this version makes a lot of sense.  Do you mean there may be problems removing while iterating even with an Iterator (or just a for loop like my example)?  Also: are there memory savings using an Iterator over your nested for loop example?  I'm going to be using this on pixel arrays for very large images, so I'm trying to plan ahead!

Comment: It doesn't make much difference if you use an iterator or just a for loop as in my example. I think the syntax in my example is just a short form, but internally it uses an iterator, too. Iterators are lightweight objects, using/not using them doesn't affect memory much.

Comment: About removing objects - it is possible that you simply don't pay attention and remove an element from the collection you iterate (with or without iterator) over and thus got an exception. There is nothing magic about iterator, its just a convenient form of iterating over a collection. You can simply use some int i as a counter and get elements of the collection in cycle by calling get(i) method. The effect will be the same.

Comment: @AlexKreutznaer on lightweightness of iterators: I had once encountered a case where iterators were created in a tight loop (like the one here).  The end result were frequent garbage-collection cycles (read: mysterious pause each ten seconds). So think twice before creating lots of lightweight objects - like iterators - with each frame.

Comment: @AlexKreutznaer: thanks - that clarifies a lot.  I thought Iterator's `remove()` was built differently to handle potential problems, but perhaps I misunderstood.  In any event - great solution and very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting (and hiding) lots of `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`and `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`, as you are removing from the array and at the same time you are iterating over it.

In order to avoid that you need to use an iterator:

```
final ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        final int rand = Double.valueOf(Math.random() * 255).intValue();
        nums.add(rand);
    }
    System.out.println(nums);

    for (int i = nums.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final int current = nums.get(i);
        // println(current);
        try {
            for (final Iterator<Integer> iterator = nums.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                final Integer other = iterator.next();
                if (Math.abs(current - other) < 5) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    i--;
                }
            }
        } catch (final Exception cme) {
            System.out.println(cme);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(nums);
```

Comment: Thanks - I had another version with an Iterator, but am much less familiar with the syntax, and was getting a lot of errors.